# TypeError javascript variable is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs

in my ror app（ruby on rails），one of page google.js.erb function show google map， i add add position function，i use extjs frame，however i encounter some stronger problem， relative code is below

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
var mapOptions = 
{         
    zoom: 6,     
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.26, 120.19),    
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,    
    scaleControl: true,      
    mapTypeControl: true       
};   
var map = new google.maps.Map(Ext.getDom('mapDiv'), mapOptions);
var googlemappanel=Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
items: [
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    region: 'east',
    items: [ 
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', { 
            id: 'zone-form', 
            items: [ 
            {xtype:"textfield",fieldLabel: '<%= t('code') %>',name: "code", id: 'zoneid'}
            ],
            buttons: [{
                handler: function(){
                    Ext.getCmp('zone-form').getForm().submit({   
                        url : 'basestation_edit', 
                        success : function(form, action){
                        var base=action.result.griddata
                        for(var i=0; i<action.result.griddata.length; i++){
                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(base[i].latitude,base[i].longitude),
                            map: map
                       });
                       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event) {
                       Ext.getCmp('zoneid').setValue(base[i].id);
                   })
                   }
               } 
               ....
```

when i submit the form,google marker is added to the map. however when i click the marker, firebug throw out TypeError: base[i] is undefined error, google marker is added normal, it seems variable i is recovery，set global i don't solve the problem。
any help！

Comment: `base` is not defined.

Comment: sorry， i forget type base variable，error is not here